# System freezing reason?

Tags: linux, command-line

Typing this 
`:(){:|:&};:` will cause system freeze.What is the reason behind this.

Comment: It's called a fork bomb: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Comment: Why did you make this a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:()
```

defines a function called ':'

```
{ :|:& };
```

This is the function: It calls the function itself and pipes the output to the same function ":" and puts the process in the background. (Recursive invocation) with ; it ends the function definition

```
:
```

Calls the function and creates havoc.

Comment: Note that many systems now enforce a limit on processes per user (by default) that protects you from the havoc. Not all systems do, however, so no sense in trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered on stackoverflow.com. You'll find detailed answers [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991142/how-does-this-bash-fork-bomb-work).

Comment: Shouldn't the question be closed then?

Comment: No: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates

Comment: That wasn't the only time it was asked and answered at SO either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017440/osx-malicious-terminal-command-colon-brackets-curly-brackets-apersand-etc/1017445#1017445